# Как использовать jwt?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jwt, koa.js

Пытаюсь понять как работает jwt но всё без успешно. не понимаю с чего начать и как всё будет работать. Везде написано как то поверхностно.
Сам с серверной частью знаком на начальном уровне. Но большое желание хотя бы немного овладеть ей.
Я использую koa.js + mongodb(rest). С авторизацией не разу не сталкивался. Гугл отвечает сложными статьями для меня. Где люди юзают какой то passport.js о котором я так же не имею никакого представления. 
Ожидаю развёрнутый ответ или толковую статью

Comment: на начальном уровне овладеть нельзя

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JWT не является чем то сложным и ее можно реализовать самостоятельно. Токен (как строка) состоит из 3 частей
1) заголовок
2) полезная нагрузка
3) подпись
Каждая часть разделяется точкой: S_HEADER.S_PAYLOAD.S_SIGN

Полезная нагрузка — это объект представленный как строка JSON закодированная в base64-url которая хранится на клиенте. Я делал это на С#, но на JS существует аналогичная функция для кодирования base64-url. Например мы хотим хранить в токене id юзера, метку времени (для срока годности). Создаем объект payload с соответсвующими полями, 
а далее применяем -> JSON decode -> base64-url над json-строкой.
Получим строку S_PAYLOAD.

Заголовок — хранит информацию об алгоритме подписи и другую служебную информацию. Если используется один алгоритм можно использовать пустую строку. Если же решите использовать все как с полезной нагрузкой:
объект->JSON->base64-url string. Это будет ваша S_HEADER.

И главное — подпись. Данные которые приходят в полезной нагрузке могут быть подделаны и Вам нужно проверить их, для этого применяется один из алгоритмов хеширования с паролем. Например, HMAC-SHA256 (реализации єтих хеш-функций можно найти для любого языка). Необходимо взять хеш от строки S_HEADER.S_PAYLOAD и закодировать в base64-url - это будет 3 я составляющая токена (S_SIGN). Пароль для хеширования (создания контрольной суммы) должен хранится в защищенном месте на сайте.
Таким образом получаем JWT-токен строку: S_HEADER.S_PAYLOAD.S_SIGN.

Что дальше? Пользователь обращаясь к серверу передает строку токен. Сервер заново вычисляет контрольную сумму (если алгоритмов несколько то "берется" из S_HEADER) от S_HEADER.S_PAYLOAD с тем же паролем что при генерации токена. И проверяет совпадает ли контрольная сумма с переданной в S_SIGN. Если нет отвергаем этот токен, его подделали) 
Если совпадают получаем объект полезной нагрузки. Для этого проварачиваем все дело в обратном направлении : S_PAYLOAD->JSON decode->base64-url decode->наша полезная нагрузка. Извлекаем от туда expire (срок годности) проверяем, и если он годен вытаскиваем id пользователя.

Правильно создать класс генерации токена, его проверки, получения полезной нагрузки.

Чем механизм jwt отличается от сессий? Все данные хранятся на клиенте в открытом виде, но он не может их подменить. Подпись (контрольная сумма) позволяет убедится что это вы выдали этот токен и все данные валидны.

Таким образом что необходимо для реализации jwt:

1. json encode и decode
2. base64-url encode, decode
3. HMAC-SHA256 или другой механизм для генерации контрольной суммы

Answer (score 3):

JWT работает точно так же, как и другие протоколы авторизации (OAuth, OAuth2), разница только в том, что JWT позволяет заэнкриптить данные о юзере в токене. Покажу на примере Koa + PostgreSQL:

```
import * as Koa from 'koa';
import * as Router from 'koa-router';
import * as bodyParser from 'koa-bodyparser';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { Pool } from 'pg';
// dotenv - пакет, который читает `.env` файл и сеттит `key-value` из файла в `process.env`
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { compare } from 'bcrypt';

config();

// Секретный ключ для хеширования и наоборот, можете сгенерить его на сами и засеттить в `.env` файл `SECRET=some_key`
const { SECRET } = process.env;

const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: 'конекшн к базе'
});

const compareAsync = (data: string, encrypted: string): Promise<boolean> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        compare(data, encrypted, (error: Error, same: boolean) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }

            resolve(same);
        });
    });
};

const app = new Koa();

app.use(bodyParser());

const router = new Router({
    prefix: '/api'
});

router.post('/login', async (ctx: Context) => {
    // Юзер логинится и шлет запрос на `/api/login`
    // с username + password
    const { username, password } = ctx.request.body;

    // Попытаемся вытащить юзера из базы с таким `username`
    const { rows } = await pool.query(`
        SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1
    `, [username]);

    // Если такого пользователя нету
    if (rows.length === 0) {
        ctx.body = {
            message: `User with username '${username}' doesn't exist`
        };
        // Вернем статус `UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY`
        return ctx.status = 422;
    }

    const user = rows[0];
    // Сверяем пароли
    const same = await compareAsync(password, user.password);

    if (!same) {
        ctx.body = {
            message: 'Invalid credentials'
        };
        return ctx.status = 422;
    }

    // Если такой юзер существует, то берем его `id` и хешируем в токене с помощью Вашего секретного ключа
    const { id } = user;
    const token = jwt.sign({
        id
    }, SECRET, {
        expiresIn: 864e5 // 1 день
    });

    // Далее сеттим токен в куках с флагом `httpOnly`, так безопаснее так как клиент не имеет доступ к ним
    ctx.cookies.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`, {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 864e5), // 1 день
        secure: true
    });
    ctx.body = {
        id,
        email,
        username
    };
});
```

Далее просто в контексте Koa создаем `middleware`, который на каждый запрос будет делать что-то определенное, а именно проверять токен:

```
import { verify } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config();

const { SECRET } = process.env;

export const authMiddleware = async (ctx: Context, next: () => Promise<void>): Promise<void> => {
    const authorization = ctx.cookies.get('Authorization');

    if (!authorization) {
        return ctx.status = 401;
    }

    const token: string = authorization.split(' ')[1];

    try {
        verify(token, SECRET);

        return next();
    } catch (e) {
        return ctx.status = 401;
    }
};
```

Теперь этот `middleware` Вы можете использовать следующим образом в местах, где нужно делать проверку на токен:

```
import { authMiddleware } from './authMiddleware';

......

router.get('/users', authMiddleware, async (ctx) .....)
```

Можно передавать сколько угодно `middleware`, `koa-router` ждет `tuple` после роута